# accessing multiple values from hash ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

This code snippet

```
room = Room.find(roomId)
```

returns a single column from room table, the returned value contains multiple attributes, like `id`, `name`, `description`, `duration`.

I want when coding

```
render json: room
```

to return only `duration` and `name`.
Do i have to write something like that

```
render json: room[:duration, :name]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `only` option of [**`as_json`**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json) to include only certain attributes.

```
render json: room.as_json(:only => [:duration, :name])
```

Answer (score 3):

query that will only give you the attributes that you want :

```
room = Room.select(:id, :duration, :name).find(room_id)
```

Comment: This actually will still include key-val pairs for every single column, even if you didn't include them in the `select`. The other values will just be nil.

Comment: @maxpleaner actually it doesn't. the only thing it does that for is id, if blank. `user = User.select(:id, :email).find 152265` returns `=> #<User id: 152265, email: "dev@test.edu">`

Answer (score 0):

You're slightly incorrect when you say `Room.find(roomId)` returns a "single column from the room table". It actually returns a single row.

Anyway, there are a few ways you can do this.

A good starting point is to use the `.attributes` method on a model to convert it to a Hash.

So for example say you have a user with a name, email, and id columns in the database. You can call `user.attributes` to get
`{ "name" => "max", "email" => "max@max.com", "id" => 5 }`.

you can select just the name and email with

`user.select { |k,v| k.in?("name", "email") }` and then call `to_json` on the result.

To avoid having to write custom to_json code for each controller response, you can overwrite `.attributes` in the model. Say my User table has a password column that I never want to expose in my API:

```
class User
  def attributes
    super.reject { |k,v| v.in?("password") }
  end
end
```

Then, if you need to return a list of users as JSON:

```
render json: { users: @users.map(&:attributes) }.to_json, status: 200
```

The answer by Pavan will work as well, by the way.

Another approach is to use `jbuilder` and create json "views" for your records.

Comment: you are right, i was incorrect for writing column instead of row, thanks for your answer